# How to find out if user has logged out from Facebook iOS using Graph API?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

```
self.logInButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
self.logInButton.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Native 
//Above Uses Facebook iOS setting
//login if User is logged in from their device setting

if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil{ 
    //User is not logged in
} else { 
    //User is logged in
}
```

- I use above code to find out if user has logged in already.
- The above code works until user hasn't logged out from web or iOS Facebook login from settings

I need to find out a way if any of those occur. I was wondering if Facebook SDK registers some kind of notification to know if Login status has been changed or not.

Would FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate trigger "loginButtonDidLogOut" if someone logs out from Facebook not from my App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use the Facebook login delegate method.

This is Objective-C but the method call should be similar:
- (void) loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton;

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate

Comment: Will this work even if the user doesn't log out using my App?

Comment: Yes. This will simply tell you that the user is not logged into facebook. The button will change from saying log out to login with facebook. Which will allow the user to relog into facebook which you can also check with the delegate.